# Group of all $2\times2$ matrices where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are integers modulo $p$, Herstein Q$26$ Page $37$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Let $G$ be group of all square matrices of order $2$ $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$

such that $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are integers modulo a prime number $p$, such that $ad-bc\ne0$. $G$ forms a group relative to matrix multiplication. What is order of $G$?

I have tried for smaller values of $p$ by explicitly writing matrices. But how do I do this for general $p$.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you want the matrix to be invertible over $\mathbb{F}_p$. In order for the matrix to be invertible, you want the columns of the matrix to be $\mathbb{F}_p$-linearly independent.

For the first column, you can choose any **nonzero** vector in $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ (which has order $p^2$), so you have $p^2-1$ choices. For the second column, you can't choose any multiple of the first column. There are exactly $p$ such multiples, so you now have $p^2-p$ choices for the second column.

Since you have $p^2-1$ choices for the first column and $p^2-p$ choices for the second column, the total number of invertible matrices is $$(p^2-1)(p^2-p) = p^4-p^3-p^2+p.$$

Note that this argument can be generalized to prove that the total number of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is equal to $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)(p^n-p^2) \cdots(p^n-p^{n-1})$.

Comment: What is meant by order of $(F_{p})^{2}$ .How is it $p^{2}$ ? Why there are $p^{2}-1$ choices ? Can you add glorified details ?Thanks

Comment: Is that because of the cartesian product of {0,1,2,3---p-1} elements to forms two tuple vectors ?

Comment: Yes, it's a cartesian product, so there is a pair of vectors from {0,...,p-1}.

Comment: How will the argument go for SL group

Comment: Can you elaborate on how there are p multiples of first columm

Comment: Any 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$ itself, which has $p$ elements.